# How to declare where clause to retrieve object witth empty has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
Post has_many :images
Image belongs_to :post
```

I want to select all posts that have no images.

```
Post.includes(:images).where.not(images: nil) # FAIL
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://deepakmahakale.github.io/blog/2016/06/16/include-scoped-associations.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to select all posts that have no images

You were close with your `where.not` thing.

Here is conventional way to achieve it:

```
Post.includes(:images).where(images: { id: nil })
```

Comment: I think this will still run `n+1` queries?

Comment: It's not running n+1, just not working. Did you test this ?

Comment: @BartekGładys I want you to leave your comment here so **everyone** who does Rails sees it ;) But that's fine, with time you'll also learn it better. Till then you are free to downvote on perfectly valid answers, no offences on my side.

Comment: Realy? Your solution didn't work ... Try this on something similar example. I can back my downvote, if you are injured :(

Comment: I thoguht, we talking about issue in rails, not about english grammar. :) Just hide your pride, and try your solution on something similar example.

Comment: @BartekGładys so did you finally try it and realized that it's correct?

Comment: Yes, on other example. Your solution select all posts that have images. But in question is : "I want to select all posts that have no images."

Comment: @BartekGładys I removed the `not` part (which I not intentionally left there) like 20mins ago

Comment: @BartekGładys I should have downvoted the Deepak's answer as well by your logic. What I did instead is just said him that he is as well returning posts that have images (meaning he forgot to use `not`) - he edited the answer and that's it. It's not a war here man, take it easy and be constructive, not just saying it's not working

Comment: I commented 30 mins ago and also in same time you wrote your solution is correct. I back downovte :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with the following :

```
Post.includes(:images).where.not(id: Image.pluck(:post_id).uniq)
```

If you want to `include` an association with condition you need to create a new association with condition.

Something like:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :published_posts, -> { published }, class_name: 'Post'
end

# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
end
```

Comment: this is wrong in a sense, that it will return all posts **with** images, I think you meant to use `where.not(id: Image.pluck(:post_id).uniq)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `includes`

```
Post.includes(:images).reject{ |p| p.images.any? }
```

Note that this will first fetch **all** Posts and then iterate over them. Its not the database doing the main work for you here, instead, ruby/activerecord creates an object for every post and then queries the post.

Comment: processing db with Ruby - bad ;)

Comment: Hi, i edited your question about why this is not the preferred approach (the main work should be done by the db). Hi revoked my downvote. Dont take it personally, its a valid answer, but not very good practice.